# Django group by foreign key aggregation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-aggregation

I have three models like this:

```
class Coin(models.Model):
    symbol = models.Charfield()
    
class User(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.Charfield()
    
class Portfo(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            "user",
            "coin",
        )

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        to=User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        related_name="portfo",
    )
    coin = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Coin,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=False,
        related_name="owners",
    )
    available = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=40,
        decimal_places=20,
        default=Decimal(0),
    )
    blocked = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=40,
        decimal_places=20,
        default=Decimal(0)
    )
```

I'm going to calculate each user's portfo value so I wanted to aggregate portfo objects grouped by users like this:

```
 [
    {
      "user_id":1,
      "portfo":{
           "coin_1_symbol":Decimal("1"),
           "coin_2_symbol":Decimal("2"),...
          }
    },
    {
     "user_id":2,...
    },...
]
```

or this:

```
[
 {
    "user_id":1,
    "portfo":[
           {"coin_symbol":"some_symbol","total":Decimal("1")},
           {"coin_symbol":"some_symbol2","total":Decimal("2")},...
    ]
  },...
]
```

I tried aggregation with values but it returns this result:

```
>> Portfo.objects.exclude(available=0,blocked=0).annotate(total=Sum(F("available")+F("blocked"))).values("user_id","total","coin__symbol")

[{"user_id":1,"coin__symbol":"some_symbol","total":Decimal("1")},{"user_id":1,"coin__symbol":"some_symbol2", "total":Decimal("2")},...]
```

Is there any way to do this with django orm?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to that just using annotate. Preferred way to do such things is using [Nested Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).

For now what you can do is manually convert output from your query into desired result by following code.

```
for d in data: # data is your mentioned output from query.
    user_id = d["user_id"]
    if not converted_data:
        converted_data.append({"user_id":user_id,"portfo":[d]})
        continue
    for c in converted_data:
        if c["user_id"] == user_id:
            c["portfo"].append(d)
            break
    else:
        converted_data.append({"user_id":user_id,"portfo":[d]})
```

Comment: thank you bro, so, there's no way to handle this by database side?

Comment: @salar403, No, usually, these things are done by serializers or manually.